# How to store c++ structures with __attribute__((packed)) in MySQL database?

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, sql-server, c++11

How can I easily store and retrieve c++ structures of any size with **attribute**((packed)) in MySQL DB?

Structure example:

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed))
{
    signed char result;
    unsigned char errorCode;
} Response; 

typedef struct __attribute__((packed))
{
    unsigned char   rackId;
    unsigned char   subRackId;
    unsigned char   cardId;
    unsigned char   cardType;
    unsigned char   cardSubType;
    unsigned char   portId;
    Response        ret; 
}Configure;
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use something like Protobuf or flatbuffer to handle it or you would encounter compatibility issue in the near futrue.

Answer (score 0):

Since everything is char the `packed` attribute is pointless, just `static_assert(sizeof(Configure) == 8);`.

You can store it as CHAR(8).

If you have a struct with different types try arranging them so no padding occurs (static_assert the size to make sure). It's even better to add manual padding than to use `packed`.

But if you must use `packed` you should use an unpacked structure to work with and only copy the data to a packed structure to write to mysql and copy out of the packed structure after reading from mysql. Never access a packed structure more than once, the access will be horrible slow on many architectures.